# Why would a fusible AC disconnect require a bonded neutral when a non-fusible disconnect only requires the equipment grounding conductor?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

According to the GE Spec-Setter TM datasheet their AC disconnects are comprised of three varieties: *fusible*, *no fuse*, *non-automatic*.

A GE diagram on that datasheet for their "*fusible*" disconnects shows a BONDED NEUTRAL. Since the NEUTRAL is supposedly only bonded once per system, usually in the main breaker panel, why would the GE disconnect **with fuses** require that you BOND the NEUTRAL?

It is known that many HVAC systems only require 240 V AC, and a ground, so in those cases there is no NEUTRAL conductor in their disconnects, which suggests that these GE **fused disconnects** that require BONDED NEUTRAL are designed for the case where they are controlling the power going to a combination 120/240 utilization equipment.

And, though outside the scope of the question, what does GE mean by *non-automatic* disconnect? Their diagram appears to show a ganged 2-pole switch.

I found the [GE datasheet](https://buy.wesco.com/Electrical-and-Power-Distribution/Disconnects/Air-Conditioner-Disconnect/GENERAL-ELECTRIC/Switch-Air-Conditioner-Pull-Out-240V-AC/p/78316420987-1?signalId=G_331879&signalPosition=3&signalPage=null&queryId=mH8hB71zr4) as a PDF at the buy.wesco.com website.

Comment: If you could edit in a link to the data sheet you're looking at, it would help us all be on the same page.

Comment: I agree with the data sheet is needed.  if a “main disconnect as a fused disconnect can be” it would require a bonded neutral, I put in small separately derived systems regularly and it is common for this to be the main. but as a safety disconnect bonding would be a code violation.

Comment: From this PDF https://library.industrialsolutions.abb.com/publibrary/checkout/DET-845?TNR=Brochures%7CDET-845%7CPDF&filename=Safety%20Switch%20Brochure%20DET845B_final.pdf page 18, it says "Bonding strap can be used to ground factory
installed neutral for service entrance applications" I don't have code experience that the gurus here have, but it appears these devices can be the first device in the electrical service after the meter, thus the place where ground and neutral would be bonded.

Comment: You missed the meaning of the term service entrance this is a main disconnect as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @Ed Beal This question is about AC disconnects, or HVAC disconnects, not a MAIN disconnect. I could not find the term "safety disconnect" in the NEC. You say that "as a safety disconnect bonding would be a code violation." Could you reference that section of the NEC?

Comment: @Triplefault My question is not about the service entrance equipment main disconnect. I am aware that is where the Main Bonding Jumper ties together the GROUND BUS BAR and the NEUTRAL BUS BAR, bonding them together. My question is about the types of disconnects that are used to turn off power to an HVAC unit before servicing.

Comment: @Guiermo just because disconnects like that are used for HVAC units, doesn't mean they're ONLY used for HVAC units.  Next time you see a billboard that has lights, take a look where the electricity comes from. That would be one of the disconnects you linked, and it's a service so it's bonded.

Comment: @Triplefault your PDF is helpful, as it expands my view of what GE manufactures. The datasheet that I had downloaded was a 2-page PDF titled "Safety Switches AC Disconnects -- Spec-Setter (TM) Safety Switches," with a date of 2-22 BuyLog Catalog www.geelectrical.com Revised 1/08. Your PDF is titled Spec-Setter* Safety Switches, which is more general and has a copyright date of 2018 [8.18 DET845B]. The datasheet I was going by has 10 AC disconnects that do not appear in the document you referred me to. However, in your PDF there is a reference to further documents (8) that might help.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine  An electric service does require bonding of the neutral and ground. At a service entrance is also a main disconnecting means, for example at my house the main breaker is 200 Amps. The Main Bonding Jumper is in that circuit breaker box. The AC disconnects I am referring to are simple straight through power wires in power wires out enclosures controlled by a pullout., fused or not, that interrupts power to a downstream utilization equipment before servicing. I cannot see how one of these could be used to connect the power company to a billboard. What am I missing?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine and Ed and Triplefault
Have you downloaded the GE datasheet from the link I posted? I want to make sure we are on the same wavelength. Those 10 AC disconnects are either fused, non-fused, or non-automatic. Are you trying to tell me that the fused versions are commonly used for other applications where an electric service is needed? If just having fuses in those boxes allows the power company to wire up a meter and then you wire from the meter to the box, then bond the neutral and voila, it turns out to be a service entrance, that answers my question. I can accept.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease How did you fix my link? I just arrived on the last boat and need all the help I can get.

Comment: I was able to untangle the link and saw the data sheet. And yeah you're right, they call them "air conditioning disconnects".  But that is kind of the slang for disconnects of that size.  Anyone can [edit] a question or answer, and you just hand-typed the markup and used {} where [] is correct on this platform.  I mainly use the buttons above for links and pix, it does a better job too.

Comment: @ Ed Beal How do I ACCEPT your answer as being correct? I looked back at the datasheet and there was a list under "Air Conditioning Disconnects" one entry of it said:     FUSIBLE - UL869 and right after that SERVICE EQUIPMENT. You are correct, but I refused to imagine a "fused disconnect" as being a "Main disconnect." Next time, I am going to be thinking a little harder when I read someone's answer here. It's like a light bulb turned on, so thanks. That's a breath of fresh air, knowing people here are not dumb, or even average.

Comment: You just click the check next to the answer I do this for a living and did not need the instructions but made a “SWAG” scientific wild ass guess. But was curious where you got the idea, I know the terms but those that don’t do this every day don’t.

Comment: @ Ed Beal    Thanks for letting me know how to accept your answer. What idea, you were curious about where did I get what idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fused disconnect can be a main disconnect and if used  as a main or service entrance disconnect the neutral is required to be bonded by code.

A non fused or safety disconnect requires over current protection so it would not be the main and it would be a code violation to bond beyond the main service entrance panel, the 99 code update made this change as I remember.

If the fused disconnect is used as a safety disconnect it would be a code violation to bond at this point.

So the difference is the wording “service entrance” requires bonding

Comment: This is it. People think that services are only for houses. They are also for railroad crossing gates, weather stations, guard shacks and the like.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine perhaps it is more like people get used to seeing an object for what they think it is, and just haven't enough capacity to think of it in more creative ways.

Comment: @Guiermo Well the industry is full of that, for instance "mobile home feeder" which is used for lots of NON-mobile home uses.

Comment: Actually anytime a transformer is used it can be a service 1:1 or 2:1 more common in commercial or industrial sites as the transformer creates a separately derived system and the reason a fused disconnect has the instructions a safety disconnect is not required to be fused.

Comment: @EdBeal Please help me understand. In a Ryan Jackson video "100 Days of Article 100: Separately Derived System" he drives home the point that a "Service" can only be obtained from a utility (of course they supply their service from a transformer). And the Article 100 definition of a "Separately Derived System (SDS)" says it is a power source that is NOT a service (yes, from a transformer). You say ANY TIME a transformer is used it CAN be a service? But from customer supplied transformers? I realize that the fused disconnect used in the SDS case would need to have its neutral bonded.

Comment: Actually a generator (gas, diesel, wind or solar) or a transformer ARE separately derived systems and the secondary of the transformer is required to have the neutral ground bond as it is a separately derived system as defined by code although rare I have provided a service to a residence (120/240) from a 480 3 phase industrial system where there was isolation required.I have no idea who Ryan Jackson is and any one can make a video there are many on the internet from non licensed persons

Comment: @Guiermo Youtube is full of idiots, but Ryan is talking about **the normal use-case** in a pre-solar pre-"cut the cord" everyone getting all their electric from the utility and just crying in the dark when the power goes out.  Now that we have *options*, services are popping up all over. Yet still, a railroad crossing gate will take a disconnect just like that.

Comment: Ok this should be my last comment NEC 450.6.5.C where the secondary tie is grounded each transformer secondary supplying the supply shall be grounded in accordance 250.30 for separately derived systems. Exhibits 250.14 & 250.15 show delta wye transformers as separately derived systems 250.15 is the most widely used for 3 phase 480 to 208/120 used in most commercial residential but each unit gets single phase , I tried to show the most direct links but article 250 is full transformers that require bonding and how a transformer is connected can affect how it’s classified. Same as generators.

Comment: @EdBeal Re your first comment. Thanks for info on separately derived systems (SDS). Ryan Jackson is a NEC code guy associated with Mike Holt. He was once an electrical inspector, and also teaches the NEC via YouTube videos. A good resource. I pointed to one of his videos as something you might want to watch, in which he said three important things: You can only get a SERVICE (See Art. 100) from a utility. A generator is not a SERVICE. A customer owned transformer is NOT a SERVICE. The second 2 are SDS. While the first is a SERVICE, all require NEUTRAL GROUND BOND where they come in, I think.

Comment: From Article 100 (NEC). SERVICE:  The conductors and equipment for delivering electric energy from the SERVING UTILITY to the wiring system of the premises served. SEPARATELY DERIVED SYSTEM:  An electrical source, other than a SERVICE, having no direct connection (s) to circuit conductors of any other electrical source other than those established by grounding and bonding connections. SERVICE and SEPERATELY DERIVED SYSTEM have precise meanings in the NEC. Can we have consensus on these terms? My goal is learning, so must eliminate any possible confusion.

Comment: @EdBeal your "last comment". . .   what are Exhibits 250.14 & 250.15?  Tried both 2017 and 2020 NEC with no success. Did try to understand the concept of hooking two or more transformers together with the secondary tie concept to deliver electric power, especially since you say it applies for generators also. Need to learn more.

Comment: The exhibits are pictures of examples. I have the hand book. I  thought all the exhibits were in the standard code book but I have been using this version for so many years I did not realize they were not in the regular, publicly available book. The hand book is expanded code by the authors what most inspectors & masters use as it explains the reason for code segments and well provides examples ( it also cost more). As far at tying I have not seen this done with residential class transformers as winding differences will cause problems but when getting in to 100’s KW or MW there less variations